# Can creatures that can see color in completely different visible spectrum exists?

Tags: vision, life, senses

From wikipedia - "The visible spectrum is the portion of the electromagnetic spectrum that is visible to the human eye."

So humans can see the light from 400-700 nm and this is because our eyes can interpret/sense this little portion of the electromagnetic spectrum.

I wonder - could somewhere out there exist a creature which is possible to see different part of the spectrum ? I know that on Earth a creature can have a different visual spectrum "flavour" but I do not know whether it is possible the visible spectrum to be completely different - e.g. on some other planet can creatures exist that can say to see light in lets say  1500-2000 nm ?

Comment: maybe [this] (https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58005/are-there-animal-species-that-sense-infrared-light-with-their-eyes) can answer your question. They show animals on Earth that uses different molecules to transduce the visual stimuli, which is the key element to sense different portions of the electromagnetic spectrum, here on Earth, and in any planet as long as I can tell.

Comment: See also https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/57708/what-is-the-biological-potential-for-vision-of-wavelengths-outside-the-human-vis/57710 - may be considered a duplicate. Note that speculation about completely foreign biology is not on-topic here, questions have to be about real biology that can be studied.

Comment: From what I have read so far - asking this question about life vision on other planets - is an on the edge on sci-fi and assumptive. As we haven't found complex life on other worlds - we can guess. However as far as what I read - based on the conditions the life live (e.g. their star type, distance from it etc.) and their chemistry - maybe life could be completely different - their vision could theoretically be different as well - sensing their world in different spectrum of light.

Comment: Maybe this question is similar with asking - could vehicles engines be completely different from what we have now on Earth. I suppose yes.